# Linux Input/Output error on huge file after 193GB has been copied

Tags: ubuntu-20.04, ntfs, veracrypt

I'm trying to copy a veracrypt image from a (veracrypt) encrypted ntfs drive which is mounted on `/mnt/veracrypt`. However, the copy consistently fails at 193GB (out of 2TB).

```
$ sudo cp /mnt/veracrypt/some_file.hc /slow-data/
cp: error reading '/mnt/veracrypt/some_file.hc': Input/output error
$ du -sh /mnt/veracrypt/some_file.hc 
2,0T    /mnt/veracrypt/some_file.hc
$ du -sh /slow-data/some_file.hc 
193G    /slow-data/some_file.hc
```

Is there a way to debug this? E.g. to check whether the file is damaged or whether the destination has some issue - even though it says "error **reading**". Can the file not be adequately allocated? Veracrypt took 6 hours to create the image and then it took 10 hours to copy all the files in the image, without any errors. Is there some limit of 193GB in some system? I unmounted the disk properly before attaching it to a new computer.

The file system of `/mnt/veracrypt` as well of `some_file.hc` is NTFS, and the destination `/slow-data/` is a RAID ext4. It crashed twice, consistently at 193GB.